# discord.py bot message deleting not working

Tags: discord.py

my code is

```py
@bot.command()
async def on_message(message):
    if 'Congratulations' in message.content:
        await message.delete(message)

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

However whenever I type Congratulations the message wont get deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code provided in your question is a command, it would not be listening for an `on_message` event, as the command must be invoked by a user.

This is an event applied to your code, it would always wait for a message, only if the message contains "Congratulations", will trigger the message delete

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'Congratulations' in message.content:
        await message.delete()

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `await message.delete()` instead of `await message.delete(message)`.

Comment: unresolved attribute reference delete_message for class Bot

Comment: Ok, instead try `await message.delete()`.

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you, the `await message.delete()` is from the official discord py documentation, and it should work without error.

Comment: Ok, try this out: `await message.channel.purge(limit=1)`

Comment: oh wait I realized what you're doing incorrectly - you are using `@bot.command()` instead of `@bot.event`. Replace your `@bot.command()` line with `@bot.event`, since `on_message` is an event. Then, try `await message.delete()`.